# CouchDB Map/Reduce to an array

Tags: couchdb, mapreduce

I have a number of documents which look like this:

`{userId: 123, msg:{ timestamp:123456, event:"actionA"} }`

`{userId: 123, msg:{ timestamp:123466, event:"actionB"} }`

`etc...`

Map fn:

`emit(doc.userId, [doc.msg])`

Reduce fn:

`return [].concat.apply([], vs)`

These functions seem to do what I expect, so I'd thought I'd see output like:

`Key: 123, Value: [{timestamp:123456, event:"actionA"}, {timestamp:123466, event:"actionB"}, ...etc...]`

But, I am getting a *reduce overflow error*, "Reduce output must shrink more rapidly".  Indeed, the [couchdb docs](http://guide.couchdb.org/draft/cookbook.html#aggregate) say that "As a rule of thumb, the reduce function should reduce to a single scalar value." ... "CouchDB will give you a warning if you try to use reduce “the wrong way”".

So, I guess I'm using Couch MR the "wrong way".  What would be the "right way" to do this kind of calculation?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've hit this too before. CouchDB likes tall lists, not fat lists. In other words, you can probably get what you want with *keys* in the view, and not reducing them to the same thing.

If you want to see all messages from a userId, you do not need a reduce function. Simply query your view with `?key=123`. You will see all messages for that userId and there is no limit to the size.

If you are unhappy with the format (if you simply *must* change the JSON that couch sends you), then Simon's list function link is correct.

Answer (score 2):

I think the right way is to use a [*list* function](http://guide.couchdb.org/draft/transforming.html). You can have your list function output JSON if that's what you want.